# Let $p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(2k)!}$ and $q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(2k+1)!}$. Show that $(p(x))^2 = 1 + x(q(x))^2$.

Tags: analysis, power-series

Define $p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(2k)!}$ and $q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^k}{(2k+1)!}$. Having shown $2p'(x)=q(x)$ and $p(x)-q(x)=2xq'(x)$, deduce that $$(p(x))^2 = 1 + x(q(x))^2\tag{1}$$

I am not sure how I should use the 2 equalities shown to get the final result. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit, moving content from comments:** I've noticed that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the even and odd terms (respectively) in the series expansion for $e^x$.  I can then use standard even/odd constructions ($e^x+e^{-x}$; $e^x\cdot e^{-x}$) to turn an identity for $p$ and $q$ into an identity about exponentials.  But is it possible to show (1) *without* using properties of $e^x$?  Ideally, I would just use the derivative formulas for $p'$ and $q'$ mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hint: $e^x =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k/k!$, i.e. *all* the terms. You can isolate $p,q$ according to their parity.

Comment: @Integrand Thanks for the hint! I've done some working and I'm not sure how this can get me to the answer. What do you mean by isolating $p$,$q$ - is it using $p$ and $q$ to construct $e^k$? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here

Comment: For example, write $e^x+e^{-x}$ as a series.

Comment: Hint: $e^fe^{-f} = 1$ and $p^2-xq^2 = (p-\sqrt{x}q)(p+\sqrt{x}q)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Got it - thanks very much for your method! Any idea what I could do to get the answer by using $2p'(x)=q(x)$ and $p(x)-q(x)=2xq'(x)$?

Comment: @Integrand Hi, Ninad gave me a method to get the answer - but I'm still going to try what you are suggesting if it's not the same as his method

Comment: @Integrand Got it using your method! Fundamentally the same as Ninad's approach. Is there a way to answer the question just using the fact that $2p'(x)=q(x)$ and $p(x)-q(x)=2xq'(x)$, and not manipulating $e^\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @Integrand Did you notice these terms have exponent $k$ paired with denominators $(2k)!$ or $(2k+1)!$? That mismatch makes these terms differ from those in the series for $e^x$. For example, the terms here include $x^{1}/2$, but in $e^x$'s series, the linear term is just $x$.

Comment: @alex.jordan I think his clue still managed to work in the end for me. Calculating $e^\sqrt{x} +e^\sqrt{-x}$ gets you $2p(x)$. $e^\sqrt{x} - e^\sqrt{-x}$ gets you $2\sqrt{x}\times q(x)$. Then you can evaluate $(p(x))^2-x(q(x))^2$ to get 1.

Comment: @alex.jordan I meant $e^{-{\sqrt{x}}}$ instead of $e^\sqrt{-x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${d\over dx}p^2=2pp'=pq=(q+2xq')q=q^2+2xqq'={d\over dx}xq^2$$

Comment: So no knowledge of exp is required.

Comment: Would the 1 come in as a constant after integrating both sides?

Comment: Two functions with the same derivative differ by a constant.  Evaluate both at zero (where $p$ is $1$).

Comment: @David Ok thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 1):

$$p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(2k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\big[\sqrt x]^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\cosh \left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$
$$q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(2k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\big[\sqrt x]^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}=\frac 1{\sqrt x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\big[\sqrt x]^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$(p(x))^2 = 1 + x(q(x))^2 \implies \cosh^2 \left(\sqrt{x}\right)=1+\sinh^2 \left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for another method to do this! Much appreciated